# Meaning of quantization of energy

Tags: quantum-mechanics, energy, atomic-physics, orbitals, discrete

I am trying to understand the concept of energy quantization. For example, Sodium. Let's talk about $2p$ and $3s$ for this example. So $2p$ has 6 electrons and and $3s$ has one.
So when we say energy is quantizied does it mean that all 6 electrons in $2p$ has same energy?

Answer (score 1):

Energy quantisation means that the electrons in an atom (or molecule) can only have discrete, that is allowed, values of total energy. If, say, $E_1$ and $E_2$ are such adjacent values, then energy levels $E$ with $E_1<E<E_2$ are not allowed. Solutions of the Schrödinger equation determine the allowed levels of $E$.

The allowed energy levels for atoms depend only on the *principal quantum number* $n$, so that all electrons with quantum number e.g. $2$, such as electrons in the $2p$ orbital, have the same energy levels. This is called *degeneracy*.

Comment: thx. just making sure, I get it . So for N=3, 3s, 3p and 3d orbitals all will have same energy.?

Comment: That's right, yes. $E$ depends on $n$ only.

Comment: @Gert, Actually, that is true only for hydrogen (1 electron only), the energylevels depend then only on n. However, in larger multi-electron atoms the energy depends on the other quantum numbers as well and 3s, 3p etc. do not have the same energy. This is atually producing the periodic table of elements.